# What is the best way to limit the IP addresses which can be access from within a docker container?

Tags: docker, iptables

I have an answer which will limit docker containers to only be able to access a single IP address outside the host.  Using this iptables rule on the host:

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0  ! -d 8.8.8.8 -j DROP
```

means that from inside any docker containers it is only possible to access the IP address 8.8.8.8.

This is fairly drastic - basically, if the destination is NOT 8.8.8.8 then drop the packet.

What is the best way that I can set up rules which would allow me limit the containers to a certain number of IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of specific addresses to which you want to permit access, you may want to investigate the `ipset` command, which allows you to maintain a list of ip addresses in the kernel that can be used by iptables rules.  This may drastically simplify your ruleset.

Create a new ipset:

```
ipset create dockerdests hash:ip
```

Add some addresses to the set:

```
ipset add dockerdests 8.8.8.8
ipset add dockerdests 162.13.208.130
```

Create an iptables rule referencing the set:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i docker0 -m set --match-set dockerdests dst -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -i docker0 -j DROP
```

These commands insert two rules at the top of the `FORWARD` chain; the first will accept packets going *to* or *from* anything listed in the named ip set, and the second rule will drop anything coming in on `docker0` that was not accepted by the previous rule.

If you go this route, you would need to arrange to load your `ipset` configuration when the system boots.

More information about `ipset` can be found [here](http://ipset.netfilter.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - seems to be fairly elegant.  Couple of questions.

What are the '1' '2' and 'dst' values in the first command for?

Wouldn't entering the rules in that order put the DROP all command at the top of the chain?

Is it not possible to invert the first line - such as :

iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -m set ! --match-set dockerdests -j DROP

This may have the advantage of a single iptables rule.

Comment: I would say that this is the best solution.  

Adding/removing IP addresses from the ipset is easy and instant.  Once the rules have been added to the firewall they don't need to be changed.  

The numbers '1' and '2' are the rule positions in the chain.  

The part of the rule  
  
`-m set --match-set dockerdests dst`  

is clean enough.  It means use iptables extension module ipset (-m set) and match the set dockerdests (--match-set dockerdests) and apply this to the destination of the packet (dst).

Comment: Glad it helped! Looks like you have figured out most of the  answers to the questions in your first comment.  I did not test negation rules (`!`), so I don't know for certain if that would work or not.  It's worth testing, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice with iptables is first to drop everything from ALL IP OR PORT. And then open some ports individually.

Here his an example (a script) I use to manage ports, but I assume you can do the same with IP :

```
#!/bin/sh

# reset :
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Block all :
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Authorize already established connections :
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Authorize backloop :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Authorize ssh :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize HTTP :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize HTTPS :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize DNS :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Ping :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Authorize FTP :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

# # Authorize NTP :
# iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize IRC :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize port 10000 (for Node.JS server) :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize port 631 (Cups server) :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Duh!!!

Long day - no excuse etc...

I assume I can add a few records along the lines of...

If IP1 then allow.
If IP2 then allow.
If IP3 then allow.
Everything else then DROP.

This seems to work:

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0  -j DROP
# iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0  -d 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0  -d 4.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
```

which results in iptables rules of:

```
root@jessie-amd64:~# iptables -L -n 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            4.2.2.2             
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            8.8.8.8             
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:22
root@jessie-amd64:~#
```